# DNS,SSL - Local Network

Tags: networking, dns, ssl, https, letsencrypt

I have a server with 2 IPS: 177.68.XX.YY (public IP) 192.168.10.1 (local IP)

This server has a SSL certificate (from Let's encrypt) for https://example.com

There are several devices on this server local network (such as 192.168.10.10, 192.168.10.11, and so on) that access this server through it's public ip address (https://example.com).

However, when the internet is down (which on the past few days have been quite often due to several maintenances on the building) all devices have to switch to 192.168.10.1 in order to access the server (unsecure, without https).

My question is: is there any way of using DNS inside my network so that when internet is down people on the local network can still access the domain through https://example.com?

Comment: Can you run DNS on the server? Or would you rather just hand-modify the hosts files on the client computers?

Comment: Why does the server's public IP become inaccessible when the Internet is down? Isn't that the public IP of your Internet-facing router interface? Is that router going offline? Or is the problem that your network has no local DNS servers and they become inaccessible when the Internet is down?

Comment: There are mtiple solutions depending on your router. You could also bypass DNS altogether by hard coding IP mappings on each PCs hosts file.

Comment: @music2myear I could run DNS on the server, no problem!

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, the devices are only on the "192.168.10.X" network, so they aren't able to "see" 177.668.XX.YY. The router is online, but I don't have local DNS server (that might be the solution).
What about the SSL? Will I still be able to use https when I map example.com to 192.168.10.1?

Comment: @davidgo I use RouterBoard Mikrotik RB750Gr3. Is it possible to solve this problem only by configuring router?

Comment: If your DNS server becomes inaccessible when the Internet goes down, that's why you're losing connectivity. Either get an internal DNS server, or put an entry in your computer's HOSTS file pointing example.com to the internal IP of your server. If you do that, yes, SSL will still work. You can easily test and confirm that.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, instead of implementing a DNS Server on my Server, am I able to do so in the Mikrotik Router? It is a RB750Gr3

Comment: @pedrofialho I'm not familiar with that unit but I'm sure if it's possible the user manual would say so. That certainly would be a good solution.